# Uploading artifacts to nexus in npm

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, npm, nexus

Can we upload npm artifacts into the nexus using `curl` command. I have built dist directory in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done using the REST API:

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Components+API#ComponentsAPI-NPM